# Discord.js: "Unknown Message" when trying to delete a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This script is meant to send a message that'll keep track of the process log of a Minecraft server, and as soon as it finishes loading, it should delete the message:

```
let statusBase = "Opening server...\n";
let statusMessage = await message.channel.send(statusBase + "` `"); 

// This function executes on the process's stdout and stderr's "data" event
async function onData (data) {
    if (data.indexOf("Done") != -1) {
        mcserver.process.removeAllListeners();
        message.channel.send("Server open");
        console.log(statusMessage); // Used this for debugging on this issue. Yes, it prints stuff on the prompt.
        statusMessage.delete();
    } else {
        statusMessage.edit(statusBase + "`" + data.toString() + "`");
    }
}
```

but for some reason it just throws me an "Unknown message" error as soon as it gets to the line where it's supposed to delete the message. I don't see anything wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: Try adding a check. `if (statusMessage) ... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. The issue was not in the `delete()` method, but rather on the `edit()` method that was trying to edit the message when it had already been deleted.

Here are the changes to the function:

```
async function onData (data) {
    if (data.indexOf("Done") != -1) {
        message.channel.send("Server open");

        // Unrelated to this issue but I was removing the message and error listeners the wrong way before
        mcserver.process.stdout.removeAllListeners();
        mcserver.process.stderr.removeAllListeners();

        // Wait for the message, then delete it
        await statusMessage;
        statusMessage.delete();
    } else {
        // Check if the message still exists in that channel, and return if it doesn't
        if (statusMessage.channel.messages.fetch(statusMessage.id) == null) {
            console.log("nope");
            return;
        }

        // Edit the message
        statusMessage.edit(statusBase + "`" + data.toString() + "`").catch(() => {});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to delete a message 5 seconds after sending:

```
message.channel.send("Server open").then(message => message.delete({ timeout: 5000 }));
```

Comment: It's seems the poster wants the message to be deleted when `onData()` is called, not automatically

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `delete` when the message still on process to send, expect that if 3 or 4 code lines in the same if else statement, all of them going to execute at once.

So you can do like this to delay the deleting after the sent message.

```js
 mcserver.process.removeAllListeners();
 message.channel.send("Server open");
 console.log(statusMessage);
 setTimeout(() => {
   statusMessage.delete();
 }, 1500) the timer is a ms form.
```

[image: Sample SetTimeout Function]